# If $\nabla f(x,y) \cdot (x,y) = f(x,y)$, then $f$ is first degree homogeneous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, homogeneous-equation

Given $f$ differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. We're asked to prove that if $\nabla f(x,y)  \cdot (x,y) = f(x,y)$ for all $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f$ is an homogeneous function, i.e. $f(t(x,y))=tf(x,y)$ for $t>0$ and $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

My prof. explained that proving the consequent amounts to proving that

$$g(t) = \frac{f(tx_0, ty_0)}{t}, t>0,$$

is a constant function, which in turn amounts to showing that its derivative is 0 everywhere. But how do we justify that $g(t) = f(x_0,y_0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, once you show that $g$ is constant, you'll have $$f(x_0,y_0) = g(1) = g(t) = \frac{f(tx_0,ty_0)}{t}$$for all $t >0$, and so $f(tx_0,ty_0) = tf(x_0,y_0)$. Since $(x_0,y_0)$ was arbitrary to begin with, we're done. Now, we use the chain and quotient rules to get $$g'(t) = \frac{f(tx_0,ty_0) - (tx_0,ty_0)\cdot \nabla f(tx_0,ty_0)}{t^2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can even solve the differential equation.

In polar coordinates the equation becomes
$
r\hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \left( \hat{\mathbf{r}} \partial_r f + \hat{\mathbf{\alpha}} \partial_\alpha f \right) = f,
$
i.e.
$
r \, \partial_r f = f
.
$

The solutions to this are given by
$
f = C(\alpha) \, r
= C(\arctan(y/x)) \, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
,
$
where $C$ is a differentiable function.

Thus,
$$
f(tx, ty) = C(\arctan((ty)/(tx))) \, \sqrt{(tx)^2+(ty)^2} = C(\arctan(y/x)) \, t \, \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = t \, f(x,y).
$$

Comment: But isn't $f(x, y) := \sqrt{xy}$ another solution (and as with your solution, all constant multiples are, too)? How many solutions are there? For your solution to be complete, wouldn't we have to verify the first degree homogeneity of all solutions of this first order PDE?

Comment: [Continued] Also, for the solution $\sqrt{x y}$, there is a generalization to functions of $n$ variables, namely $\sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n}$. Is there something similar for your specific solution of the differential equation?

Comment: @Ramanujan. Note that $C$ is a function (it wasn't clear before my edit). The case $f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$ corresponds to $C(\alpha)=\sqrt{\cos\alpha \sin\alpha}$ and $f(x,y)=ax+by$ corresponds to $C(\alpha)=a\cos\alpha + b\sin\alpha.$

Comment: Is there a generalisation of your approach for the differential equation $$\nabla f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$?

Comment: @Ramanujan. The solution is basically the same: $f(r\mathbf{n}) = r g(\mathbf{n}).$